# How can i ignore generated files while using sloccount

Tags: lines-of-code

how can i ignore sloccount.sc and xml files created when using sloccount
I use the following command:

```
sloccount --duplicates --wide --details . | | sed "/\/\.svn\//d" | tee sloccount.sc
```

i am using sloccount version 2.26

But i am also unit tests results in the same folder as sloccount results, so sloccount picks up the XML Files

Answer (score 0):

I am using a following line to ignore the sloccount.sc:

`sloccount --duplicates --wide --details . | grep -v sloccount.sc | tee sloccount.sc`

You could add a `| grep -v .xml` in there to ignore the xml files, or use egrep to find `.xml$` if you are worried about files that could have .xml in the middle of the name